# Mysql join issue to get values when parent id is not present in child table

Tags: mysql

I need a help in the mysql query.

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `lea`.`account_id` 
FROM `lists_list` AS `main_table` 
INNER JOIN `list_account` AS `lea` ON lea.list_id=main_table.id 
INNER JOIN `list_customer` AS `customer` ON main_table.id = customer.list_id
WHERE ((`customer.customer_id` = '1') OR (`lea.account_id` = '1'))
```

Now my problem is, I need to show lists that have a link type of "B" / "C" that have no list accounts in list_account and list_customer table , if the customer's Account matches that type in lists_list table

Could you please help in this.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and show expected output? It is hard to understand exactly what you want.

Comment: May I suggest you investigate the `LEFT JOIN` sql operation?

Answer (score 1):

That is actually pretty easy, just use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `lea`.`account_id` 
  FROM `lists_list` AS `main_table` 
  LEFT JOIN `list_account` AS `lea` ON lea.list_id=main_table.id 
  LEFT JOIN `list_customer` AS `customer` ON main_table.id = customer.list_id
  WHERE ((`customer.customer_id` = '1') OR (`lea.account_id` = '1'))
```

An `INNER JOIN` requires a record on the left and right side to exist, while `LEFT JOIN` will also return records where the right side does not exist (leaving the fields from that table with `NULL` as their value).

Comment: I have been asked to write a query which will show all listid(main table.id) which do not contain list(listid) of a particular type in maintable.type. I need both the correct matched item's and the empty I'd which don't have entries in account table.

Comment: I need to show both matches and  non-matches of particular account type

Comment: Sorry, I don’t get your problem from the comments. Maybe you need to use `right_table.id IS NULL` in the `ON` clause to exclude records where the right side of the relation exists?